# Как передать переменные в контроллер методом POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть страница сайта, на которой генерируется арифметическое уравнение с рандомными числами из модели уравнения (при обновлении страницы каждый раз новые числа в уравнении).

Как передать эти сгенерированные числа в контроллер методом POST?

Контроллер:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index(AnswersTask answersTask)
        {
            return View(answersTask);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult MyPost([FromForm] int x)
        {
            

            //SaveResult(x, y);

            return Ok();
        }
```

В представление передается модель ответа с рандомными числами(генерируются в конструкторе класса) и в этой модели содержится поле для ответа, соответсвенно оно получает переменную с формы:

```
@model AnswersTask

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    int x = @Model.Mass;
}

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/ajax.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Тренажер по решению сквозных задач</h1>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Тело массой <b>m = @Model.Mass КГ</b> движется по закону: <b><i>X = X₀ + U₀t + at²/2</i></b></label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Дано уравнение: <b>X = @Model.R_x0 @Model._znak @Model.R_u0 t + t²</b></label>
</div>
<form method="post" id="ajax_form" asp-action="MyPost">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="_a">Полное ускорение в начальный момент времени</label>
    <input asp-for="_a" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите ответ">
    <span asp-validation-for="_a" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Возможно ли, например, передать переменную икс и т.д? Я понимаю что можно реализовать через параметры адресной строки методом get, или даже через куки, но нужно именно post запросом

Comment: [HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyPost([FromForm] int x, [FromForm] int y) {
 SaveResult(x, y); //do something;
 return Ok();
}

Comment: @Konst я передаю в представление модель с переменными, как мне получить обратно эти же переменные? В представлении не понимаю как реализовать передачу

Comment: исправьте свой вопрос, добавьте код представления и контроллера

Comment: посмотрите туториал: https://makolyte.com/aspdotnet-core-get-posted-form-data-in-an-api-controller/

Comment: @Konst добавил код

Comment: добавьте все параметры своей модели в форму отправки в виде input type=hidden  , в методе контроллера же MyPost([FromBody] AnswersTask answer)

Comment: @Konst спасибо, выручили